# PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true) not returning method for properties from base class

Tags: .net, reflection

I have following test program:

```
public class FooBase
{
  public object Prop {
    get { return null; }
    private set { } 
  }
}
public class Foo :FooBase
{
}
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MethodInfo setMethod = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Prop").GetSetMethod(true);
    if (setMethod==null)
      Console.WriteLine("NULL");
    else
      Console.WriteLine(setMethod.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey(); 
  }
}
```

And it shows "NULL" if I run it. If I move property definition to class Foo then I works as expected. Is this a bug in .NET?

Comment: Please explain the down vote, valid question.

Comment: I changed the title. Never expect a bug but suspect your understanding and make question titles that are readable for other so they understand if the question is interesting for them. BTW: I didn't down vote but I guess it has to do with the title.

Comment: Sorry for not informative title. But your one was not correct too. I've changed to correct one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it by getting the PropertyInfo on the declaring type of the property, simple extension method could be...

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static MethodInfo GetSetMethodOnDeclaringType(this PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   {
       var methodInfo = propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);
       return methodInfo ?? propertyInfo
                               .DeclaringType
                               .GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name)
                               .GetSetMethod(true);
   }
}
```

then your calling code does...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       MethodInfo setMethod = typeof(Foo)
                                 .GetProperty("Prop")
                                 .GetSetMethodOnDeclaringType();
       if (setMethod == null)
            Console.WriteLine("NULL");
        else
            Console.WriteLine(setMethod.ToString());
         Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is by design.  The FooBase property setter is not accessible in the Foo class, no matter what you try:

```
public class Foo : FooBase {
    void Test() {
        Prop = new object();  // No
        ((FooBase)this).Prop = new object();  // No
    }
}
```

You'll have to use typeof(FooBase).GetProperty("Prop") in your code.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Sorry,

You are correct in your comment below. The error is different. There is no set method in the Foo class that is why it is not returning a method. It is not there because it is private in the base class.

Comment: No, GetProperty itself returns correct value - otherwise there will be exception here. GetSetMethod method doesn't return valid value.

Comment: Boolean param of GetSetMethod is true, that means that private setter should be returned too. There is nothing in MSDN article for GetSetMethod about work of this method with props of base types.

Comment: But the answer seems to be right, if you change the visibility from private to protected it works. You could make a post on Microsoft Connect about this issue.

Comment: A private method of a base class is NEVER available in the derived class. No matter what boolean you pass.